# Get tokens in DocuSign in Python

Tags: python, api, jwt, docusignapi

I am working in a project and I am trying to get the access token to use the DocuSign API, but the call to get the oauth userinfo does not work.

- Authentication type: [JWT Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken)
- Python SDK: [docusign-python-client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client)

The code:

```py
class BaseDocusign:
    api_client = None
    _token_received = False
    expiresTimestamp = 0
    account = None

    def __init__(self):
        BaseDocusign.api_client = ApiClient()

    def token_is_expired(self):
        current_time = int(round(time.time()))
        return (current_time + DOCUSIGN_EXPIRE_TIME - 10) > BaseDocusign.expiresTimestamp

    def check_token(self):
        if not BaseDocusign._token_received or self.token_is_expired():
            self.update_token()

    def update_token(self):
        client = BaseDocusign.api_client
        client.request_jwt_user_token(
            DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_ID,
            DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID,
            DOCUSIGN_AUTH_SERVER,
            DOCUSIGN_PRIVATE_KEY,
            DOCUSIGN_EXPIRE_TIME
        )
        if BaseDocusign.account is None:
            account = self.get_account_info(client)
            print account

        BaseDocusign._token_received = True
        BaseDocusign.expiresTimestamp = (int(round(time.time())) + DOCUSIGN_EXPIRE_TIME)

    def get_account_info(self, client):
        client.host = DOCUSIGN_AUTH_SERVER
        response = client.call_api("/oauth/userinfo", "GET", response_type="object")

        if len(response) > 1 and 200 > response[1] > 300:
            raise Exception("can not get user info: %d".format(response[1]))

        accounts = response[0]['accounts']
        target = target_account_id

        if target is None or target == "FALSE":
            # Look for default
            for acct in accounts:
                if acct['is_default']:
                    return acct

        # Look for specific account
        for acct in accounts:
            if acct['account_id'] == target:
                return acct

        raise Exception("User does not have access to account {target}\n")
```

When I run it:

```py
a = BaseDocusign()
a.update_token()
```

The access token is generated:

```js
{"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQkAAAABAAsADQAkAAAAZjczYjYxMmMtOGI3Ny00YjRjLWFkZTQtZTI0ZWEyYjY4MTEwIgAkAAAAZjczYjYxMmMtOGI3Ny00YjRjLWFkZTQtZTI0ZWEyYjY4MTEwBwAAq89LFJXXSAgAAOvyWVeV10gLAB8AAABodHRwczovL2FjY291bnQtZC5kb2N1c2lnbi5jb20vDAAkAAAAZjczYjYxMmMtOGI3Ny00YjRjLWFkZTQtZTI0ZWEyYjY4MTEwGAABAAAABQAAABIAAQAAAAYAAABqd3RfYnI.f_XW63iL5ABts-gq48ciWKQnaYyNiIEG9rC_CpnyWo0Hzf-B_G3hIRUWJzD1Yiyyy4pKm_8-zoalsoqANcMeXsjwBTCMlXIhc216ZWa6nHR6CheRbfTHM6bJ1LKwRdmnpwLywu_qiqrEwEOlZkwH_GzSSP9piUtpCmhgdZY1GFnG2u9JU_3jd8nKN87PE_cn2sjD3fNMRHQXjnPeHPyBZpC171TyuEvQFKCbV5QOwiVXmZbE9Aa_unC-xXvvJ2cA3daVaUBHoasXUxo5CZDNb9aDxtQkn5GCgQL7JChL7XAfrgXAQMOb-rEzocBpPJKHl6chBNiFcl-gfFWw2naomA","token_type":"Application","expires_in":28800}
```

But when try to get the account info, the call fails:

```js
{"error":"internal_server_error","reference_id":"f20e360c-185d-463e-9f0b-ce95f38fe711"}
```

To do this, I call to the `get_account_info` function and it calls to the endpoint `oauth/userinfo`, but the call fails.

```py
response = client.call_api("/oauth/userinfo", "GET", response_type="object")
# Response: {"error":"internal_server_error","reference_id":"f20e360c-185d-463e-9f0b-ce95f38fe711"}
```

To do this [example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email), I need the variable `account_id` and according to this example, the `get_account_info` function gets it.

I have also tried to do what the [web](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) says (step4) to get user information and the answer is:

```sh
curl --request GET https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo--header "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAAAABAAUABwAAYWSFlJrXSAgAAMko55ya10gCAP-ftnA70YROvfpqFSh7j7kVAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAZjczYjYxMmMtOGI3Ny00YjRjLWFkZTQtZTI0ZWEyYjY4MTEwIgAkAAAAZjczYjYxMmMtOGI3Ny00YjRjLWFkZTQtZTI0ZWEyYjY4MTEwEgABAAAABgAAAGp3dF9iciMAJAAAAGY3M2I2MTJjLThiNzctNGI0Yy1hZGU0LWUyNGVhMmI2ODExMA.YHFoD2mQbwh8rdiPi8swg9kO9srlDyJcpqUo8XI5tdZki2I_Nla-qb9VaD4gAy8tSXVSY7unRjfClFDAqC8Ur73caHuZo7tN5tIKmXi6C3VzPWPGFJtsceKNEGMqwznw6OBVuPQG0IGlRjXK37Ur1nILLUWKb7w6O5Uz6y0e5uR8sxzZWh1adm2zHqd6khiQuAFB9vG2sS3jaudtck1qV6HRB_kARvUie1zglvHydc42Nc_o5GtIm3sGrqW7rio3YpHVX39nTKM-28kjOvPSNwzXp3IlZtaxuB6EdexrECH19nIaNbCe29LrdpzreRMyjEwwM309bOaKJ1KV82NbTQ"

# Response
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://account-d.docusign.com/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Facing the same problem, did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking into the code, the return is "acct", a dictionary. So you need to use `account['account_id']`

I found this full example: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt

And in here: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt/blob/master/example_base.py#L44

you see how they are passing the account_id

Hopefully this helps. good luck

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the problem is when I try to get the `account_id`, the endpoint `"/oauth/userinfo"` fails. The response is `{"error":"internal_server_error","reference_id":"f20e360c-185d-463e-9f0b-ce95f38fe711"}`

Answer (score 0):

You must use `request_jwt_user_token` not `request_jwt_application_token`

See the code example: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt/blob/master/example_base.py#L34

`request_jwt_application_token` is only for some of the DocuSign organization APIs.

### Added

> From the comment:
>   I have changed the call to request_jwt_user_token and I get another token, but it still fails. The response is {"error":"internal_server_error","reference_id":"846114d0-1bcd-47a6-ba23-317049b54d00"}

Answer:

You're calling the /oauth/userinfo API method. But the Authorization header was not included.

One way is to set the Authorization explicitly:

```
client.set_default_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + ds_access_token)
```

In your case, the SDK is supposed to set it for you. It could be that you're using a new `client` object, an older SDK version, or some other issue.

I just downloaded the [eg-01-python-jwt code example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt) repo and it worked fine. I suggest that you download the example app and get it running first, then update the app to your needs.

Also, check the version of the Python SDK you're using:

```
pip3 show docusign_esign
Name: docusign-esign
Version: 3.0.0
Summary: DocuSign REST API
...
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
...
```

Comment: I have changed the call to request_jwt_user_token and I get another token, but it still fails. The response is `{"error":"internal_server_error","reference_id":"846114d0-1bcd-47a6-ba23-317049b54d00"}`

Answer (score 0):

This error can be also caused by using an expired token (use the refresh end point to get a new one)